# Can I Specify Strings for MySql Table Values?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySql table that stores the users state and city from a list of states and cities. I specifically coded each state as their two letter shortened version (like WA for Washington and CA for California) and every city has the two letter abbreviation and the city name formated like this: Boulder Colorado would be `CO-boulder` and Salt Lake City, Utah would be `UT-salt-lake-city` as to avoid different states with same city name. The PHP inserts the value (`UT-salt-lake-city`) under the column `City`, but when I call the variable through PHP, it displays like this: `Your location is: UT-salt-lake-city, Utah.`
To solve this, I've been making this list of variables

```
    if ($city == "AL-auburn") { $city = "Auburn"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-birmingham") { $city = "Birmingham"; }
    else if ($city == "GA-columbus") { $city = "Columbus"; $state = "Georgia"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-dothan") { $city = "Dothan"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-florence") { $city = "Forence"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-muscle-shoals") { $city = "Muscle Shoals"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-gadsden-anniston") { $city = "Gadsden Anniston"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-huntsville") { $city = "Huntsville"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-decatur") { $city = "Decatur"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-mobile") { $city = "Mobile"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-montgomery") { $city = "Montgomery"; }
    else if ($city == "AL-tuscaloosa") { $city = "Tuscaloosa"; }
```

Is there a way I can shorten this process or at least call it from a separate file so I don't have to copy/paste every time I want to call the location?

Comment: would just stripping the 3 three characters from the sting be ok ? if so use substr() `$city= substr($city, 3); `

Comment: Why don't you store the correct city name into the database as well?

Comment: I'd have to make a new `<select>` and field in the table... But after what I was doing that would be shorter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like

```
$name = 'UL-salt-lake-city';
ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",substr($name, 3)));
```

Converts to "Salt Lake City"

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It worked immediately, and even the first letter was capitalized (I don't know if this was CSS or not). A lot easier then writing out if statements for every city in the US. Just had to change the second line to `$name = ucwords...`. (Maybe because I'm new in PHP development I didn't get that for a while.

Comment: The capitalisation is from the [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function in the PHP API. You'll notice any word in the string will have first letter capitalised.

Answer (score 2):

You need a hashmap here, you can do that as an array in PHP:

```
$cities = array(
    "AL-auburn"     => array("Auburn"),
    "AL-birmingham" => array("Birmingham"),
    "GA-columbus"   => array("Columbus", "Georgia"),
    ...
);

if (isset($cities[$city])) {
    list($city, $state) = $cities[$city] + array(null, null);
}
```

You can also store the cities array then.

---

Alternatively you can make use of the existing information:

```
list($state, $city) = explode('-', $city, 2);

$city = ucwords(strtr($city, '-', ' '));
```

You can then map the state 2-letter-codes with a hashmap to their long names again:

```
$states = array(
    'AL' => 'Alabama',
    'GA' => 'Georgia',
    ...
);

if (isset($states[$state])) {
    $state = $states[$state];
}
```

Comment: I think that this idea would be great if I didn't already have a separate field for state... I should put that in my question. But if that was the case, I would probably use this answer.

Comment: @afterimagedesign: The second part of the question is a variation of [@dangermark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12811480/367456). Feel free to get inspired. I just wanted to show how these associate arrays work so that you can safe these large collection of if's which are burdensome (and not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have names which do not directly correspond to their codes, you can use an associative array:

```
$city_names = array(
    'CO-boulder' => 'Boulder, Colorado',
    'GA-columbus' => 'Columbus, Georgia',
    // ...
);
$name = $city_names[$city];
```